# How do you take down a helicopter quickly?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

So I got the chopper in call of duty and I throw it out, and almost immediately the chopper goes down... so is there a technique for that?  If as it enters the board, you hit it with a missile, it goes down?  Or what can you do for a fast take down on a chopper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off it is important to use the right missile launcher.
Always use the Strela to shoot down choppers, the M72 has a terrible hit-rate and the RPG doesn't lock-on to aircraft.

Also, it helps (but is not required) to have ghost pro so the chopper can not see you.

Now, when the chopper starts to enter the map you should figure out which direction it is coming from using the mini map.

If it is a Chopper Gunner you should try to lock on to it as soon as possible because it takes to hits to take it down. Fire on it asap, reload and fire again. Without Ghost Pro it will often be necessary to take cover while reloading. You should then fire at it again, choosing the right moment when it is difficult for the Chopper Gunner to kill you (The further away you are from it and/or its current line of fire the less likely it is to kill you). You can take a CG down much faster with a teammate because it is unnecessary to reload.

If it is an Attack Helicopter or Gunship then you should locate it but not fire upon it. Shots at these helis almost never hit while they are entering the map. They are also very good at dodging shots once in the map so it is best to chose your moment to shoot wisely. I generally try to do it right after the heli swings around.

The most important thing is to try to shoot choppers down as much as possible. With practice, you'll develop you're own strategies eventually.

Comment: What do you mean by "the M72 has a terrible hit-rate"?. It does the same amount of damage as a Strela-3 rocket, meaning, two M72 rocket hits take down a chopper. The first shot will always be dodged, though, from any guided rocket launcher.

Comment: I'm sorry that is correct, I worded that poorly and I will edit it. It is a poor choice because it only has one shot and it takes two to take down the chopper.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest way to take down a chopper is team-work.

Make sure at least two players are equipped with the Strela-3 launcher. That means two rockets each.
The chopper always dodges the first shot, and it takes 2 rockets to go down, therefore, shooting alone will take time - finding ammo, reloading twice, etc..

Look around when you hear the distinct sound, announce the arrival of the helicopter to your team-mates, if you have a microphone.
If fired quickly upon, it can be taken down while still flying in, before it can do any harm.

Answer (score 3):

**Launchers:** Attack choppers, chopper gunners, and gunships take two hits to down, as your first "hit" is technically dodged/chaff. It does not matter if you use a Strela or M72, the fact that two hits are needed remains. You can target choppers as soon as they are visible making the first hit, the dodge, capable of being logged without the attack/gunner/gunship firing a single round.

**SAM turrets**: Useful, if your team mates are reluctant to help with anti-air. However, they place their priority on what was in the air first so if the air is full of enemy spy and counter spy planes, they will not be of much use in downing the chopper quickly (bonus: they are capable of hitting Valkyries). Downsides are their limited lifespan (1.5 minutes) and their ability to be destroyed or hacked.

Concerning attack choppers, you can down them in one hit with the RPG, but the weapon is unguided and inaccurate at range, making it a poor recommendation.

Care package helicopters can be taken out with one hit, if you are able to get a lock on the chopper fast enough, its destruction can result in the opposing team's care package to be dropped out of bounds, eliminating that kill streak reward.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the SAM turret. That is actually _the_ fastest way of taking down any aircraft.

Comment: Actually, the fastest way is to hit the chopper directly without locking on. This results in a one hit kill.